# Find homogeneous linear differential equation, given solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given homogeneous solution, find the differential equation

> $$y_h = c_1e^{-10x}+c_2xe^{-10x}$$

The factorization of equation will looks something like this
$$(\lambda +10 )(\lambda + 10)=0$$

This is as far as I can get, not sure which way to proceed to get the differential equation, any help?

Comment: Any time you have a putative solution to a differential equation, you can check its correctness by _plugging the solution into the differential equation_.

Comment: Are you sure that $10r^2+20r+10=0$ has a double root $r=-10$ ? $(\lambda+10)^2=\lambda^2+20\lambda+100$ could help, I hope.

Comment: i just realized it was wrong, do you know how to get the d.e. from the repeated root?

Comment: Given the homogeneous linear ODE with constant coefficients $ay'' + by' + c = 0$, how do you form the characteristic equation? Now do it in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

Just differentiate. 
$$ y' = -10c_1 e^{-10x} + c_2 e^{-10x} - 10c_2xe^{-10x}$$
$$ \begin{align*}
y'' & = 100c_1e^{-10x}-10c_2e^{-10x}-10c_2e^{-10x} + 100 c_2xe^{-10x}\\
& = 100c_1e^{-10x}+100c_2xe^{-10x}-20c_2e^{-10x}\\
& = 100y - 20c_2e^{-10x}\\
& = 100y -20(y'+10c_1e^{-10x}+10c_2xe^{-10x})\\
& = 100y-20y'-200y\\
& = -100y -20y'
\end{align*}$$